# Laravel Undefined property in job

Tags: laravel

In a Laravel job I have:

```
use Spatie\Valuestore\Valuestore;
```

and

```
public function __construct()
{
  $this->settings = Valuestore::make(storage_path('app/settings.json'));
}
```

and

```
public function handle()
{
  if($this->settings->get('foo') == 'test') {
etc...
```

and on this I get an error `Undefined property App\Jobs\MyJobName::$settings`. What is going wrong?

Even if I do this:

```
 public function handle()
    {
    $this->settings = Valuestore::make(storage_path('app/settings.json'));
      if($this->settings->get('foo') == 'test') {
    etc...
```

I get the same error.

**Update based on the comments**

`MyJobName` is called in a custom artisan command, that happens to also use `Valuestore` but I assume that would unrelated.

In the class `CustomCommand`:

```
use Spatie\Valuestore\Valuestore;
```

and

```
public function __construct()
{
  parent::__construct();
  $this->settings = Valuestore::make(storage_path('app/settings.json'));
}
```

and

```
public function handle()
{
  if($this->settings->get('foo') == 'test') // This works in this custom command!
  {
    $controller = new MyController;
    MyJobName::dispatch($controller);
  }
}
```

So in `CustomCommand` I use `Valuestore` in exactly the same way as in `MyJobName` but in the latter it doesn't work.
As per one of the comments: I do not make `$this->settings` global as I don't do that in `CustomCommand` either and it works fine there.

Update 2

If I add protected `$settings;` above the `__construct()` function as per the comments it still doesn't work, same error.

Comment: Sounds unrelated to the specific code you're calling. Where is `App\Jobs\MyJobName` used?

Comment: Did you add global definition of settings variable?  (eg:  public $settings;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you use JOB by QUEUE, you need all the requests or SQL queries to do by the method `handle`

```
public function handle()
{
  $this->settings = Valuestore::make(storage_path('app/settings.json'));

  ....
}
```

Because the constructor works when you make the object of class, and this object is serialized and stored in the database and after the unserialization and the handle is triggered.

Comment: All the serailization and unserialization should be done by laravel. can you explain what's wrong with the code given in the question.

Answer (score 5):

Just declare the settings property as public in your Job Class.

```
public $settings;
public function __construct()
{
  $this->settings = Valuestore::make(storage_path('app/settings.json'));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I recently had this error. I've tried to make the variables public, delete all the variable inside the `Jobs` class and even rename and delete the class itself. But it didn't work.

**Shortly, I run this artisan command** `php artisan optimize:clear` to clear all the caches, views, routes, etc. And it somehow solve the problem about variable in my problem. For anyone who is still have this OP's problem, give a try to my solution above.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to restart your **queue worker**

[From Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#running-the-queue-worker)

> Remember, queue workers are long-lived processes and store the booted application state in memory. As a result, they will not notice changes in your code base after they have been started. So, during your deployment process, be sure to restart your queue workers.

If you use a daemon `php artisan queue:restart`

If you use `queue:work` on your **bash** hit `Ctrl+C` then again `php artisan queue:work` should be enough

Comment: I’m not using Redis but the database queue driver.

Comment: @Eskimo I edited my answer. Any queue workers store your code in memory.

Comment: I did stop the queue process by closing the tab in terminal (which kills the process, right?) and then again starting `queue:listen`, but I'll try `queue:restart` later and let you know whether this worked.

Comment: I still get the same error. After closing the tab in terminal + running `queue:work` again and also after `queue:restart`.

Comment: Then you should refer to @erkan-Özkök comment. I tried on my project and to reproduce your error I did not add `protected $settings` on it and got `Undefined property: App/Jobs/Test::$settings`

Comment: Thanks, I’ll try that later and post here. So this means variable scopes are different in custom artisan commanda vs jobs?

Comment: The fact that it doesn't work with a job but does with a command is probably because worker optimize your class: [Why You should always declare your class properties](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/186446/329153)

Comment: OK. Not behind my laptop now so just to double-check: you tested with the Valuestore library and $this-settings in __construct? Then adding protected $settings solves the issue?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Comment: Thanks for testing, I’ll check it out and let you know here. Then @erkan-Özkök you can post it as an answer and I’ll accept

Comment: if I add `protected $settings;` above the `__construct()` function I still get the same error, even after restarting the queue.

Comment: @eskimo It worked for me with the same library. Can you post your full code?