# Laravel: variable available in traits when defined in controller constructor, not when defined in job constructor

Tags: laravel

If I do the following in a controller:

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
  use MyTrait;

  public function __construct() 
  {
    $this->settings = Valuestore::make(storage_path('app/settings.json'));
  }
}
```

Then `$this->settings` is available in `MyTrait`. If I do exactly the same in a custom job:

```
class MyJob extends ShouldQueue
{
  use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels, MyTrait;

  public function __construct() 
  {
    $this->settings = Valuestore::make(storage_path('app/settings.json'));
  }
}
```

then `$this->settings` is not available in `MyTrait`. Why? And I'd like that it is, but only if it makes sense of course.

Comment: What do you mean by not available in `MyTrait` for the job?

Comment: Sorry, the usage of `$this->settings` in `MyTrait` is `$this->settings->get('foo')`. In the controller example that works, when running the job I get `Undefined variable $settings`.

Comment: Can you show the line where you are getting the undefined variable error? I don't think it's in what you've showed above.

Comment: Ah you're right, it's actually the same as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56637115/laravel-undefined-property-in-job/56642798?noredirect=1#comment99893037_56642798. I can't seem to figure this one out...

Comment: I still don't see/understand where `$settings` is called though.

Comment: I get the error `Undefined variable $settings` when calling `$this->settings` (there's no place where I use `$settings`)